# Implementing computational graph and automatic differentiator for tensor and matrix

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to implement a very simple DeepLearning framework like PyTorch to have a better understanding of Computational graphs and automatic differentiation.
I implement an automatic differentiator for scalar values inspired by https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd and then I was trying to implement a tensor automatic differentiator that you can see in my code below.

```
import numpy as np
class Tensor:
    def __init__(self,data,_children=()):
        self.data=data
        self.grad=np.zeros_like(self.data)
        self._prev=set(_children)
        self._backward=lambda :0
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tensor of shape {self.data.shape} with grad {self.grad}"

    def dag(self):
        topo=[]
        visited=set()
        def build_topo(v):
            visited.add(v)
            for i in v._prev:
                if(i not in visited):
                    build_topo(i)
                else:
                    pass
            topo.append(v)

        build_topo(self)
        topo.reverse()
        return topo
        
    def backward(self):
        topo=self.dag()
        self.grad=np.ones_like(self.data)
        for v in topo:
            v._backward()

    @staticmethod
    def sum(self,other):
        _tensor=Tensor(self.data+other.data,(self,other))
        def _back():
            self.grad=_tensor.grad
            other.grad=_tensor.grad
        _tensor._backward=_back
        return _tensor

    @staticmethod
    def dot(self,other):
        assert self.data.shape[1]==other.data.shape[0],  \
            f"can't multiply two Tensor with shape {self.data.shape} and {other.data.shape}"
        _tensor=Tensor(np.dot(self.data,other.data),(self,other))
        def _back():
            self.grad=(_tensor.grad*other.data.T)
            other.grad=(_tensor.grad*self.data)
        _tensor._backward=_back
        return _tensor
```

my question is that how am I suppose to implement an automatic differentiator for when we have a matrix of input data that each input is a column vector of the matrix (like what we do in a neural network for training) because I want to implement a matrix multiplicator hardware on FPGA and connect my framework to it to do the training on FPGA.